# How to access two different private repositories created by me

Tags: github, rsa

i am having trouble pulling from two different private repos.  I followed the instructions around here and created a deploy key in my github private repo.  I have two private repos of the form:

```
https://github.com/moonresearch/trading-engine
https://github.com/moonresearch/dbreader
```

Now, when i went to my dbreader repo, i went to the settings section and added deploy keys from following the following steps:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@github.com"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)”
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I then went to my id_rsa.pub file located in ./ssh/id_rsa.pub and copied the contents and pasted into my deploy keys for the repo dbreader.  After the above steps, i can successfully do the following:

```
git clone git+ssh://git@github.com/moonresearch/dbreader.git
```

Now, when i do the same for the first repo, i am seeing a message "key already in use".  Then i created a new key called id_rsa_docker and pasted into the deployment key section for the first repo.

From my understanding here, i am supposed to create a config file in order to manage multiple deploy keys.  So i went ahead and created one in ./ssh directory:

```
Host https://github.com/moonresearch/dbreader
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile=/Users/raj/.ssh/id_rsa

Host https://github.com/moonresearch/trading-engine
   Hostname github.com
   IdentityFile=/Users/raj/.ssh/id_rsa_docker
```

After the above steps, i tried a

```
git clone git+ssh://git@github.com/moonresearch/trading-engine.git
```

I am still not able to get it to clone properly.  Error i am getting is: remote repository not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `~/.ssh/config` file should be:

```
Host dbreader
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile=/Users/raj/.ssh/id_rsa

Host trading-engine
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile=/Users/raj/.ssh/id_rsa_docker
```

And your URLs:

```
git clone dbreader:moonresearch/dbreader.git
git clone trading-engine:moonresearch/trading-engine.git
```